# string input does not work on is_na function : dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

On this function, I want to replace NA with 0. I try everything on StackOverflow to replace
the col argument in the na_replace function. My second line doesn't work.
How can I fix this?
Note: I tried most of the suggestions posted on StackOverflow, but it doesn't work for me.
Col argument is a character, and The rest of the arguments are numeric.

```
whithout=function(col,min,max,mean,sd){
   col=as.String(col)
   continuous_dataset%>%replace_na(list(sym(col=0)))
   number=which(colnames(continuous_dataset)==col)
   for(i in 1:4267){
      if(continuous_dataset[i,number]==0){
         continuous_dataset[i,number]=round(rtruncnorm(1,min,max,mean,sd))
    
    }
  
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `sym(col=0)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I have isolated the part of the workflow that is specific to your question about using `replace_na()`. For this, you can use `setNames()` to create the named list.

```r
library(tidyr)

# example dataset
mtcars_na <- mtcars
mtcars_na$mpg[3] <- NA

# character column names
col <- "mpg"

# create the named list for use in replace_na
mtcars_na %>% 
  replace_na(setNames(list(0), col))
```

Comment: That is the correct answer. Thank you